# HOW to add contents in picker view from json alamofire ,I want to pick the visitortypes as picker view so that i want to fetch it in an array

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, alamofire

```
"communityVisitorTypeList" : [
    {
      "VisitorTypeID" : 1,
      "VisitorTypeImage" : null,
      "VisitorType" : "HouseKeeping"
    },
    {
      "VisitorTypeID" : 2,
      "VisitorTypeImage" : null,
      "VisitorType" : "Driver"
    },
    {
      "VisitorTypeID" : 3,
      "VisitorTypeImage" : null,
      "VisitorType" : "Taxi"
    },
    {
      "VisitorTypeID" : 4,
      "VisitorTypeImage" : null,
      "VisitorType" : "Delivery"
    },
    {
      "VisitorTypeID" : 5,
      "VisitorTypeImage" : null,
      "VisitorType" : "Guest"
    },
    {
      "VisitorTypeID" : 6,
      "VisitorTypeImage" : null,
      "VisitorType" : "Service"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Alamofire.request(urltype, method: .get, parameters: parameters as Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:headers).responseJSON
{ (response ) in
    if(response.result.isSuccess) {
        let swiftyJsonVar = try? JSON(data: response.data!)
        print(swiftyJsonVar!)
        let resultarray = swiftyJsonVar!["responseData"].stringValue

        //This line of code covert String into JSON.
        let responseDataValue = JSON(parseJSON: resultarray)

        print( "this is:   \(responseDataValue) ")
    }
}
```

I have to get the visitor type in an array to show in picker

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. you should show us the code which you have written so far....so we can help you. This is not a "we write code for you" platform....

Comment: Edit your question to have 1) A short but descriptive title 2) the actual question in the body of the post and not only in the title 3) some code showing what you have tried

Comment: First Convert this json to Dictionary Object. Then Use below code:

    let dictArray = dict["communityVisitorTypeList"]
    let visitorTypeArray = dictArray?.compactMap({ (value) -> String? in
            return value["VisitorType"] as? String
    })

Comment: how to convert it into dictionary object?

Comment: @nidhinshiju you accepted my answer yesterday and unaccepted it now. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: actualy it not working when i tried it

Comment: @nidhinshiju edit your question and post the correct json response then. I just tried using your response from your question and what i typed was working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (looking at your post and comments, you said " ***Actualy i want to fetch the data from this json to the array***  "

If you need to use this data on a different screen or class easily. Simply declare this

```
class myViewControoler: UIViewController {
struct communityVisitorTypeList
{
static var communityVisitorTypeListCount = 0
 static var VisitorTypeID = [String]()
static var VisitorTypeImage = [String]()
static var VisitorType = [String()

}


}
```

Now on your Api Call , use this

```
AF.request(urlString,method: .post, parameters: Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:headers).responseString{
switch response.result {
case let .success(value):
    let jsonData = value.data(using: .utf8)!
    let json = try? JSON(data: jsonData)
    let vistorTypeCount = json?["communityVisitorTypeList"].count
    communityVisitorTypeList.communityVisitorTypeListCount =  
    for i in (0..<vistorTypeCount)
    {
     communityVisitorTypeList.VisitorType.append(json?["vistorTypeCount"][i]["VisitorType").string ?? ""
  }
case let .failure(error):print(error);

    break
    }
```

You can use this array on the same class by simply calling

```
communityVisitorTypeList.VisitorType
```

and if you want to call it in a different class/view

```
myViewControoler.communityVisitorTypeList.VisitorType
```

Now to fetch values from this array, you could write any function and call by communityVisitorTypeList.VisitorType[1] or 2 or 3 or with for loop !

**set your datasource n delegate**

yourPicker.dataSource = self
yourPicker.delegate = self

**now to call your functions**

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return communityVisitorTypeList.communityVisitorTypeListCount
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return communityVisitorTypeList. VisitorType[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    print(communityVisitorTypeList. VisitorType[row])
}
```

Hope it helps. Also please use search function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modal for the `communityVisitorTypeList`. since you are using the `swiftyJSON` to deal with your response you can fill the array from your response. based on the filled array you can display data in your `pickerview`.

```
let resultarray = swiftyJsonVar!["responseData"]["communityVisitorTypeList"].arrayValue
```

```
yourPicker.dataSource = self
yourPicker.delegate = self
```

following are the methods which will help you to display the value from your array to your `pickerview`

```
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return yourArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return yourArray[row].ELEMENT_FROM_YOUR_ARRAY
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        print(yourArray[row].ELEMENT_FROM_YOUR_ARRAY)
    }
```

Comment: Actualy i want to fetch the data from this json to the array

Comment: can you please post your modal as well?

Comment: json code is on th question sir and the code  i get the response but i want to fetch it to an array for the picker  (visitortype)

Comment: you have written ```swiftyJsonVar!["responseData"].stringValue``` but in your posted code there is no such key named ```responseData```. 
Can you please post the full response?